# Prestashop 1.5 URL Rewriting working ... and not

Tags: prestashop-1.5

Facing this problem :
I have two prestashop installed, one for test on winamp (works as wanted), another on Ubuntu (does not work as wanted)

*What I want to do :*

Redirect the landing page (index.php) to categories (index.php?id_category=1&controller=category).

*What I did :*

I add the following rule to the .htaccess (as mentionned [here](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/233980-set-category-page-as-a-home-page-in-prestashop-15/)) :

```
 RewriteRule ^(index\.php)$ index.php?id_category=3&amp;controller=category [QSA,L]
```

On the Ubuntu, I still have 'index.php' as home page, on the wamp, the 'id_category ...' is added.
What should I check/change on Ubuntu to make it working correctly ?

(by the way ...
the multiboutique is not working for the 2nd boutique ... I'm well redirected to the mentionned directory, but it is empty.
Feeling that the 2 problems are linked)

Comment: _“I have two prestashop installed, one for test on winamp”_ – your mp3 player acts as a web server environment executing PHP? Wow, didn’t know it had this capability.